# Not able to see Preview Button while testing AMP Page

Tags: amp-html

I have created a sample article to test [AMP page](https://jitangupta.github.io/amp/article.html).

Structured AMP Code

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
        {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "NewsArticle",
        "mainEntityOfPage": {
        "@type": "WebPage",
        "@id": "https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-web-api-using-code-first-approach-in-entity-framework/"
        },
        "headline": "Creating Web API Using Code-First Approach In Entity Framework",
        "image": {
        "@type": "ImageObject",
        "url": "https://jitangupta.github.io/amp/helpful-images/aritcle-entity-framework.gif",
        "height": 800,
        "width": 800
        },
        "datePublished": "2017-05-16T08:00:00+08:00",
        "dateModified": "2015-05-16T09:20:00+08:00",
        "author": {
        "@type": "Person",
        "name": "Jitan Gupta"
        },
        "publisher": {
        "@type": "Organization",
        "name": "csharpcorner",
        "logo": {
        "@type": "ImageObject",
        "url": "https://csharpcorner-mindcrackerinc.netdna-ssl.com/App_Themes/CSharp/Images/SiteLogo.png",
        "width": 600,
        "height": 60
        }
        },
        "description": "In this article, we will create a database with a foreign key constraint (one to many relationship), using Code First technique in an Entity Framework, seed some sample data and return the data, using the Web API."
        }
</script>
```

But while testing it on [Google Structured Data Test](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISZwD.jpg)

I am not able to view the preview button to see the real time result.

GitHub Repo :
https://github.com/jitangupta/amp/!

Comment: Instead of screenshots and links please include the relevant parts of your code in your question.

Comment: thanks for suggestion, I have updated the relevant part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like, there is different output depending upon the "@type" attribute.
With "@type": "Recipe" you will be able to "Preview" and with other like "Product", "NewsArticle", there is no preview option.
Read 2nd point's Tip here : https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/prototype

Comment: Thanks, it worked after changing the "@type": "Recipe", it is now showing the preview options.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that your page is not a valid AMP page. 
You can validate it using the validator: https://validator.ampproject.org

In order to preview your page you should use this one: https://search.google.com/test/amp
This preview option will be displayed once your page is a valid one.

Comment: I agree with you, my page is not a valid amp page, but [AMP](www.ampproject.org) has provided a [sample page](https://jitangupta.github.io/amp/codelab/final-party-coffee-cake-recipe.html) which is also not a valid AMP page, but while testing, it has the preview button.